# Нужна ли запятая после слова "мысль"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Возникает мысль оставить все как есть" — нужна ли запятая после слова "мысль"?

Answer (score 5):

Запятая не нужна. Мысль какая? Оставить... Это определение, выраженное инфинитивом. Условий для обособления нет. Сравните: Умение петь мне пригодится. Возникло желание поговорить.

Comment: Спасибо! Исчепывающе!

Answer (score 2):

Здесь, думаю, нет. Запятая не нужна. "Как есть" здесь в функции наречия ("неизменно"), ни о каком сравнении речи не идет. 
Тут, правда, может иметься в виду и юридический (торговый) термин "as is", но это отдельный разговор, на пунктуацию не повлияет.

Пардон, если действительно речь о за пятой после "мысль", то мне даже в голову такое не пришло. А зачем она вообще там, по какой мотивации?

Comment: Ответ не совпадает с вопросом!
*Возникает мысль : оставить все как есть*.

Comment: Я просто всерьез это даже не рассматривал.

Comment: grumant, спасибо! на счет двоеточия тоже думала, но лень было писать=) behemothus, зачем вообще писать коммент, когда нет конкретного ответа на конекретный вопрос? что за "медвежья услуга"!?

Comment: Почему "нет"? есть. Вот он:

Поздравляю, у груманта появился женский мульт! ;)